# How to feed multiple command to cmd.exe initiated on remote machine using psexec

Tags: python, subprocess, rpc, psexec, remote-connection

I'm trying to connect to remote machine using psexec and  execute the cmd.exe. Once I've this session open I want to run multiple commands such as mkdir, del, etc. I'm facing the problem that i can only run one command with subprocess as communicate close the pipe. Is there is any way to accomplish?

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

class WsRPC():
    def __init__(self):
        self.rpc_exec_path = r'C:\SysinternalsSuite\psexec.exe'
        self.user = 'administrator'
        self.ip = '172.xxx.xxx.xxx'
        self.password = 'XxXxXxXx'
        self.session = ''

    def wsConnect(self):
        pass
    def runCommand(self):
        try:             

            self.session = Popen([self.rpc_exec_path, '\\\\' + self.ip,  '-u',
                                 self.user,  '-p', self.password, 'cmd.exe'],
                                 stdin = PIPE,stdout = PIPE,stderr = PIPE,
                                 shell = True)
            command = 'cmd.exe /c dir'
            self.session.stdin.write('dir/r/n')
            strout, strerr = self.session.communicate()
            print strout
            print strerr
        except Exception,e:
            print str(e)

obj = WsRPC()
obj.runCommand()
```

I'm getting the following o/p when i run this code -

```
C:\SysinternalsSuite\psexec.exe \\172.xxx.xxx.xxx -u administrator 
-p XxXxXxXx cmd.exe
Microsoft Windows [Version 5.2.3790]


PsExec v2.0 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2013 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Connecting to 172.xxx.xxx.xxx...


Starting PSEXESVC service on 172.xxx.xxx.xxx...


Connecting with PsExec service on 172.xxx.xxx.xxx...


Starting cmd.exe on 172.xxx.xxx.xxx...



cmd.exe exited on 172.xxx.xxx.xxx with error code 0.
```

So it seems that my "dir" is not working.

PS: How to debug this kind of scenario too?

Comment: What does `command = 'dir\r\n'` do? Maybe you need a newline.

Comment: i tried that one too it didn't work

Comment: does the command work when you are in the cmd yourself? Could it be that the network latency is relevant?

Comment: @user if you are asking whether the program work when i run the command using cmd.exe, then the answer is yes. it works perfectly fine. for n/w latency i'm not sure how to debug it or find out that it is relevant

Comment: It would require something like `time.sleep(5)` before `self.session.stdin.write(command)`.

Comment: I've tried that and i'm getting [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Answer (score 0):

Locally I did:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> s = subprocess.Popen(['cmd.exe'], stderr = subprocess.PIPE, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, )
>>> s.stdin.write('dir\r\n') # letting out '\r\n' does not run the command
>>> s.communicate()
```

My QUestion to you is: when you do the same with the psexec - does it still work?

Using a string `connection_string` instead of a list could be a  problem. 
Try:

1. add Popen(..., shell=True)
2. use a list.

   ```
   [self.rpc_exec_path, '\\\\' + self.ip,  '-u', self.user,  '-p', self.password, 'cmd.exe']
   ```

Comment: I've changed the popen as you asked but i'm still not able to pipe the input